# Getting LONG_BIT error when installing gammu in Mac OS X using GCC 4

Tags: python, macos, gcc, gammu

I'm trying to install Python-Gammu on a mac running Snow Leopard.  I successfully configured gammu with cmake and GCC 4, but am getting this error on install.  It seems to indicate an improperly configured gcc, but i'm not sure what can be done about this.

Has anyone else run into similar problems with GCC on the mac?

```
[ 90%] Built target smscgid
[ 91%] Building C object python/gammu/CMakeFiles/python_gammu.dir/src/gammu.o
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers/Python.h:57,
                 from /Users/jgordon/Downloads/gammu-1.27.0/python/gammu/src/gammu.c:23:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers/pyport.h:761:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
make[3]: *** [python/gammu/CMakeFiles/python_gammu.dir/src/gammu.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [python/gammu/CMakeFiles/python_gammu.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Python is somehow miscompiled (or misconfigured).

You can always try building Gammu without Python support to workaround this if you don't need it.